# Program or extension to save Google News archive images?

Tags: chrome, google-apps, firefox

Ok, kind of a detailed question.

I use the google news archive a lot and I printscreen and paste what I want to save and I usually have to merge two or three parts together to get the complete object. This is pretty time consuming, so does anyone know of an extension or program which works with the news archive and would let me select the complete image/article I want at one time and automatically save it?

I have tried a couple things including Fireshot 1.12.8, Abduction 3.5, Nimbus and Pearl Crescent Page Saver. All these work great on most sites but they aren't that useful when using them on the news archive. The problem is the archive is displayed within a frame screen/window and doesn't have a scroll bar, so when I use these programs they don't allow me to scroll further down to capture the entire image I want. Even though most of them have a scroll option included, that doesn't work here.

This is what the news archive looks like if you never used it before

http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2MSJ22rj538C&dat=19920305&printsec=frontpage&hl=en

Here's an example of my problem, using Nimbus on Chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MQqy.jpg

First screenshot
In this screen, I will try to save what is in the blue square and I will first zoom in so that I get the most detail.

Second screenshot
So I am zoomed in and I select as much as I can of the top part. I try to scroll down using the mouse but it doesn't let me. I also try pulling the resize boxes down and they don't go any further.

Third screenshot
Now here I manually scroll down using the arrow keys and you see the problem. I am able to see the bottom part of the image. BUT the selection box I made also comes down, and this is why I can only save the visible part of what is on my screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems Google News uses a crafty way for displaying (old) newspapers: it puts a lot of pictures of a certain size next to each other to make it look like a big picture. Because of that you can't extract them with tools like Firebug (Net --> Images) or DownThemAll, unless you're prepared to do a lot of handiwork... (I know, because I tried it myself) I thought I had found a way to download the whole picture with Firebux, but it ended up all blurry and unreadable...

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but still relevant in 2019. The only success I've had is to configure my monitor with the image rotated 90-degrees. This allows me to expand the height of the browser page and get a screen shot of the entire article. Still clunky, but saves on the multiple image pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for Firefox:

1. Go to the newspaper page that you want to save.
2. Zoom all the way in by clicking on the magnifying glass button with the plus sign in it. (Don't zoom in with your browser. Use the zoom button in the google webpage). It doesn't matter what part of image you zoom in on.
3. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. This will cause Firefox to go into "Responsive Design Mode", or RDM for short. This mode allows web developers to simulate different monitor screen sizes or device screen sizes.
4. When in responsive design mode, there will be an additional toolbar at the top of your browser. This toolbar allows you to change the size/resolution of the simulated screen. In the toolbar, there are two boxes with an "x" in between them. Each box contains a number. These numbers are the resolution of the screen. If I recall correctly, the default screen resolution is very low. I would change it to about 5000 x 5000.
5. Zoom out using your browser zoom function until you see the entire simulated screen. (Do not try to zoom out using the zoom button on the google newspaper website. That won't work.) You may have to use the browser's scroll bars to locate the simulated screen. It is sometimes shifted far a particular direction.
6. You have two options at this point:

Option A: Click on the camera icon in the RDM toolbar. It is on the right hand side of the toolbar. It will take a picture of the entire simulated screen, and automatically save it to your downloads folder. When doing this, it doesn't matter how zoomed in or zoomed out you are using your browser zoom. The image will be the same. After the image is downloaded, you can use whatever software you want to crop the image to the desired size.

Option B: Firefox has its own screenshot tool that is similar to the snipping tool built into Windows. Right click on the newspaper, and click "Take Screenshot". Firefox will grey out the screen, and you can click and drag your cursor over the area of the newspaper that you want to save. Alternatively, when you are in Firefox's screenshot mode, if you move your mouse around you will see that Firefox highlights elements of a webpage. If you click on a highlighted element, then only that element will be selected. This is a fast way of selecting a newspaper. Once you have selected what you want, hit enter to download the image. Also, like with Option A, in terms of your browser zoom level, it doesn't matter how far zoomed in or zoomed out you are. The downloaded image will be the same size.

Comment: Brilliant. This produces a high quality image you can print off. It works well for printing one newspaper, which is what I want to do. It would be very time consuming if you wanted many newspapers.